# grep to find first content and second content of string

Tags: bash, sed, grep, cut

I have a file which contains too many codes of shell script. In this, I have grep one string "/usr/bin/rsync" whose output is as below

```
/usr/bin/rsync -arz --update --chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rwx,Do=rwx,Fu=rwx,Fg=rw,Fo=rw -e "ssh -p 7887" root@192.168.1.201:/mnt/enjayvol1/remote/* /mnt/enjayvol5/esync/naspro/remote/ --bwlimit=0 --stats -h -l >> ${LOGFILE}
```

And from this string, I want to find which enjayvol is currently in present at first and second occurrence.

I need output as the first occurrence is **enjayvol1** and the second occurrence is **enjayvol5** in above example.

I need to use two command

expected output is
for the first command 
**enjayvol1**

and for second command output is **enjayvol5**

I have used

```
firstcommand=`grep -w "/usr/bin/rsync" esync.sh  | grep -i enjayvol | head -1`
```

it shows the output as

```
/usr/bin/rsync -arz --update --chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rwx,Do=rwx,Fu=rwx,Fg=rw,Fo=rw /mnt/enjayvol1/lokesh/* -e "ssh -p 7887" root@192.168.1.201:/mnt/enjayvol5/esync/naspro/lokesh/ --bwlimit=0 --stats -h -l >> ${LOGFILE}

secondcommand=`grep -w "/usr/bin/rsync" esync.sh  | grep -i enjayvol | tail -1`
```

it shows output as

```
/usr/bin/rsync -arz --update --chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rwx,Do=rwx,Fu=rwx,Fg=rw,Fo=rw /mnt/enjayvol1/lokesh/* -e "ssh -p 7887" root@192.168.1.201:/mnt/enjayvol5/esync/naspro/lokesh/ --bwlimit=0 --stats -h -l >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Could you post a more detailed example? Something like `grep -m 1 '/usr/bin/rsync' "$filename.txt" | grep -om2 'enjayvol[[:digit:]]*'` seems to do something similar to what you are asking but your question is really unclear.

Comment: I have grep 'usr/bin/rsync' and now in this string I want to grep enjayvol first and second occurrence in this string. In above example output look like first occurrence as enjayvol1 and second occurrence as enjayvol5. I want two command for find this

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Please ignore this line I have deleted this line from my question.

Comment: @LOKESH, keep it simple please. Add sample Input and add expected output with conditions in posts rather than in comments, so that we could try to help you then.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @LOKESH, so you mean to say you will have lot of rsync commands I your Input_file? and you need only very first occurrence of enjayvol1 and 5? Also how about if they NOT come in same command can we take it 1 by 1 from different commands in your file? Also please post all Input_file In code tags in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have single rsync command and in this I have two enjayvol string present. I want to find first enjayvol and second enjayvol.

Comment: @LOKESH In your edit you lost some information about the format: your first version mentions enjayvol 0, 1, 01, 10, 11, 5 or 6 which can be matched in a regex with enjayvol(01?|1(0|1)?|5|6). If it's not important anymore, let us know.

Comment: @LOKESH Are you aware of the fact that both outputs you mention in your edited question are the same? Is this a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you(you could achieve this in single command itself). Following answer will provide all strings having enjayvol in a line.

```
awk -v RS=" " '{match($0,/enjayvol[^/]*/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
enjayvol1
enjayvol5
```

**EDIT:** If you want to search for /usr/bin/rsync string and then want to get all matches for string enjaybol then following may help you.

```
awk -v RS=" " '/${LOGFILE}/{val=""} /\/usr\/bin\/rsync/{val=1} val{match($0,/enjayvol[^/]*/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Essentially the same ++.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, I think I had enough Q and A with OP and requested OP to mention complete Input_file too, as a try I have posted this. Let's see how it goes for OP.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs Its quite common that someone asks how can I do this with X(Y) because he just don't know about Z. A good answer would recommend to use Z, if it is the preferred solution and applicable.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 What I'm missing here is the search for /usr/bin/rsync

Comment: @hek2mgl, I added a EDIT here, since OP's Input_file is not clear so it is based on some assumptions which I have written there, thanks for pointing this out sir.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, we all are here to help/learn each other, my intentions were/are to help OP/people, I have added the explanation and assumptions which I made for my answer. Please do let me know if you have any queries on same.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, I edited it, if you have any queries please let me know.

Comment: `{match($0,/enjayvol[^/]*/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){` = `match($0,/enjayvol[^/]*/){`

Answer (score 1):

`grep`ing it with the `-o` switch (I've used the output of your `grep` stored to a file `file` in the examples below. In the real world you'd pipe the output from your `grep` to below presented `grep`s):

```
$ grep -o enjayvol[^/]* file
enjayvol1
enjayvol5
```

If there are more than 2 hits in the input, you can restrict the hit count to just 2 using `-m 2` switch.

Then again, above would fail if there existed  for example `benjayvol1` (of which `enjayvol` is a substring) in the string. We can handle that using PCRE and *positive lookbehind* (where available):

```
$ grep -Po -m 2 "(?<=/)enjayvol[^/]*" file
```

See `man grep` for more thorough explanations for the switches presented above.

Answer (score 0):

**sed** solution:
So you're using a shell script, where you've put the output of a grep in vars *firstcommand* and *secondcommand*. Ignoring the fact that both have the same value in your question, you're looking for the **src** and **dst** of your rsync. Another way of getting those is using **sed**:

```
src=$(sed -E 's!.*(enjayvol(01?|1(01)?|5|6)).*(enjayvol(01?|1(01)?|5|6)).*!\1 \4!' \
 <<< $firstcommand | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

and for dst:

```
dst=$(sed -E 's!.*(enjayvol(01?|1(01)?|5|6)).*(enjayvol(01?|1(01)?|5|6)).*!\1 \4!' \
 <<< $firstcommand | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

You've edited your question, dropping the requirement of the format of the enjayvol-directorynames (0,1,01,10,11,5,6), so the regex can be simplified to:

```
src=$(sed -E 's!.*(enjayvol[0-9]).*(enjayvol[0-9]).*!\1 \2!' \
 <<< $firstcommand | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

You can do the same for the var *secondcommand* if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'/' 'index($0,"/usr/bin/rsync") { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^enjayvol/) print $i }' file
enjayvol1
enjayvol5
```